# Print a 2d array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, graphics

I have a class called squares and then I have a class called shapes. In this class is a 12x5 2d array of shapes. In the squares class is a method called draw that draws the square at (550, 75) . The squares have width of 25 and a height of 25.  The draw method in the shapes class looks like

```
    public void draw(Graphics g) {

    for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < shapes[i].length; j++) {

            shapes[i][j] = new Square();


            shapes[i][j].draw(g);


        }
    }

}
```

This draws all the squares on top of each other. How can I draw them in a 12 by 5 format? The size of the window is 600 by 600 if that helps.

Comment: Use a GridLayout(12,5) of JPanel and draw in each of the Panels.

Answer (score 0):

Change the draw method in the Squares class to take x and y coordinates as parameters.

You can then change your loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < shapes[i].length; j++) {
        shapes[i][j] = new Square();
        shapes[i][j].draw(g, i * 25, j * 25);
    }
}
```

This will mean each square is draw in to the correct position.

-- Edit --

If you can't change the draw parameters, you can add a new constructor for the Square class. This does not require its superclass to have that constructor.

```
int x;
int y;
public Square(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

Then pass in the coordinates for that Square when you create it, and modify the draw method appropriately to use these.

Alternatively, if you can't change the Squares class at all, you could translate the graphics coordinates. The square gets drawn at (550, 75), so if we translate the graphics coordinates by (-550, -75) it will appear as if we are drawing at (0,0). We can then incrementally translate for each subsequent square.

```
g.translate(-550, -75);
for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < shapes[i].length; j++) {
        shapes[i][j] = new Square();
        shapes[i][j].draw(g);
        g.translate(0, 25); //Move down by 25
    }
    g.translate(25, 0); //Move across by 25
}
```

(Note that I haven't tested this.)

Comment: I can't change the parameters of the draw method because the program uses inheritance. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: @Krae See my edit, you can add a constructor that takes the x,y parameters and save them to use later.

Comment: @Krae Which method, adding a new constructor or translating? I would recommend adding a constructor if you can as it's probably easier.

Comment: the translating. How would I modify the draw method once I've changed the constructor?

Comment: @Krae Presumably in your draw method the numbers 550 and 75 get used somewhere. Just replace these with x and y. Now each instance of a Square will use its own values for x and y to draw itself, so they'll all be in different positions.